# In PHP, when I call a MySQL stored procedure using PDO, and then another query, I get an error:

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In PHP, when I call a `MySQL` `stored procedure` using `PDO`, and then another `PDO` query, just like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1','user1','password1');

$query = "CALL get_token()";
$stmt = $dbh->query($query);
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table1`";
$stmt = $dbh->query($query);
$array = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The `MySQL` `stored procedure` is about like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_token`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE token CHAR(64);
    DECLARE expire SMALLINT;

    SELECT `token`, `expire` INTO token, expire FROM `token`;

    SELECT token, expire;
END$$
```

And I got the following error message (using `try...catch` to catch it):

> General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered
>   queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). 
>   Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql,
>   you may enable query buffering by setting the
>   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

Even if I followed the instructions described in the above error message (that means using `fetchAll()` and setting the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` attribute), I still got the same error message.

If I change the first query to a normal `SELECT` SQL query, instead of a `stored procedure`, I won't get this error. So it seems that the problem arises from the `stored procedure`.

But how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try doing what's suggested in error message?

Comment: I followed the two suggestions in the error message, but they both didn't work. :-( @Mark

Comment: I've tried two methods mentioned in the post you recommended to me, that is using `$stmt->closeCursor()` or `unset($stmt)`. But unfortunately, they both didn't work for me. :-( @jiboulex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are not freeing the cursor of the first query. It still waits for another `fetchAll`. From http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

> If you do not fetch all of the data in a result set before issuing your next call to PDO::query(), your call may fail. Call PDOStatement::closeCursor() to release the database resources associated with the PDOStatement object before issuing your next call to PDO::query().

So `$stmt->closeCursor();` after first `$array = $stmt->fetchAll();` should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried this, but still got the same error message.
`$dbh->closeCursor();` seems should be `$stmt->closeCursor();`. I've tried the latter one, but the problem still exists. :-( @Mark

Comment: Technically `fetchAll()` ends the buffer but doesn't close the cursor, so in theory you wouldn't need a `closeCursor()` to prevent buffer errors

Comment: Then why did I got this error, since I've used fetchAll(), and even used `$stmt->closeCursor;` as well? @DarkMukke

Comment: See my answer below

Comment: Yes, thank you! `$stmt->closeCursor();` does work. The problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` OR `fetchAll()`
as they conflict

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-use-buffered-query) :

> PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY (integer)
>   If this attribute is set to TRUE on a PDOStatement, the MySQL driver will use the buffered versions of the MySQL API. If you're writing portable code, you should use PDOStatement::fetchAll() instead.

In other words,
`fetchAll()` tries to close the buffer
but `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` keeps it open

Comment: I've tried the both. And even more used `$stmt->closeCursor();`, and used `unset($stmt);` as well. But all of them didn't solve my problem. It's still the same.

Comment: `unset($stmt);` will never work because the buffer is in the mysql api, the only way that would work is if you close the session too (eg in php open a new connection)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! `$stmt->closeCursor();` does work. The problem is solved now.